# Save image position javascript after using absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

So Im trying to write JS code that make a picture in a slideshow to increase is size and then show a button. The picture size and the button I figured out but one of the thing that is a issue that I use absolute position to set to new size picture place. My problems are:

1)that I dont know how to bring the picture to his previous place after closing the window.

2)Closing the window when pressing everywhere but the image(not a must.

3)Not moving the image just showing the same picture bigger with blurry scree(will probably solve all the problems).

I'm doing this for a school project and i need to know how the code work I know how to read code and understand it but for some stupid reason if we use packages we need to understand the package code too is please no packages:);

sorry for the long read but thanks for the helpers

PS. didn't do the slideshow yet but I just want to be sure I can do all of this before building it
JS:

```
<script>
    $('#Test').click(function(){
        $('#Test').animate({
            height: screen.height * .45,
            right:  screen.width * .35,
            left:  screen.width * .2, // heigth / 2
            top:'200px' // width / 2
        });

    });

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<img src="Pics/up-arrow.png" id="Test"/>
```

CSS:

```
    #Test{
width = 400px;
position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might look at use [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) and simply remove the inline style that the animation adds to the element

```
$('#Test').removeAttr('style');
```

Alternatively you can use `$('#Test').data()` to store anything you needed before the event and use it to restore things afterwards

```
var $el = $('#Test');
$el
   .data('dimensions',{height: $el.height(), width:$el.width()})
   .animate(/* opts */)
```

Then later on to reset:

```
$el.animate( $el.data('dimensions'));
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qud9stv8/1)**</kbd>

Comment: That work(used the first option) but do you know how to:

1) making the background screen blurry
2)Animate the picture back to his place?